# Duplicate entry '213' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

Onde está o erro? Duplicate entry '213' for key 'PRIMARY'

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%%PREFIX%%shipping_vars` (
  `variableid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `methodid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `zoneid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `modulename` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `variablename` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `variableval` text,
  `varvendorid` int unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`variableid`),
  KEY `modulename` (`modulename`)
) TYPE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `%%PREFIX%%shipping_vars` (`variableid`, `methodid`, `zoneid`, `modulename`, `variablename`, `variableval`, `varvendorid`) VALUES
(213, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'meios', '40010', 0),
(211, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'senha', '', 0),
(212, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'meios', '41106', 0),
(210, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'id', '', 0),
(209, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'displayname', 'Correios', 0),
(208, 19, 1, 'shipping_correios', 'is_setup', '1', 0);
```

To tentando instalar essa DB mas da esse erro Duplicate entry '213' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: Funcionou normalmente: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef888, mas voce definiu que `variableid` é `auto_increment`, mas no insert está atribuindo valores a ele

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `%%PREFIX%%shipping_vars` (
```

É um comando que é ignorado se a tabela já existir, então o que acontece é esta tabela já existe

E os valores de insert já estão na tabela, pois é provável que você já tenha tentado antes.

Se você verificar usando o phpmyadmin verá que os dados já estão lá.

Acaso queira reinstalar, você terá que limpar a tabela, ou deleta-la